# Rest Web Service throwing Error while retuning JAXB object

Tags: java, json, jaxb, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I have written Rest API for my application which produce and consume JSON.
My application get xml node object from backend system which i am unmarshaling into object using JAXB2 jars.I have checked by printing into logs statement object unmarshalling is happening and getting runtime error when i invoked Rest API.

I am using Jersey2 for REST API implementation.

I have written following code snippet to do achieve that,

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance("com.myapp.testapi.schema");

// create binder
Binder<Node> binder = jc.createBinder();

// get response object from list of responses
Node xmlNode = (Node) responses.get(0);

// unmarshal the xml
JAXBElement<Object> jaxbObject = binder.unmarshal(xmlNode, Object.class);

Object resp= jaxbObject.getValue();

// Final return statement of Rest API
return Response.status(Status.OK).entity(resp).build();
```

Exception i am getting when i invoked REST API,

```html
           <b>exception</b>
            <pre>javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.json.bind.JsonbException: Invalid count of arguments for setter: public void com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.ElementImpl.setIdAttributeNS(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,boolean)
 org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:432)
 org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:370)
 org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:389)
 org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:342)
 org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:229)
 org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
<
```

Any help/pointer regarding issue really appreciated.

Comment: Sharad, the exception trace is no where related to your code. What is the complete stack? And why are you marshalling your node to generic Object.class? Shouldn't it be your pojo class?

Comment: Dynamic object in the XML node format i am converting into JAX Object so that JAXRS use for converting  it to JSON .